# process files and their names in a directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I am new to the terminal world and would like to process some images in a directory. Some examples of images are as follows (they are from the foggy cityscapes dataset):

```
frankfurt_000000_000294_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.01.png
frankfurt_000000_000294_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.02.png
frankfurt_000000_000294_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.005.png
munster_000000_000019_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.01.png
munster_000000_000019_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.02.png
munster_000000_000019_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_0.005.png
```

Note that `_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_` part of the names are common to all the images and the part before that is used to identify different images. I would like to first separate these images into three separate sub-directories with respect to `beta` suffix of 0.01 or 0.02 or 0.005. And after separating the files, I would like to remove the file name after `_leftImg8bit`, for all file names in a subdirectory, while retaining the `.png` extension.

Could someone help with the linux (CentOs to be specific) terminal commands as I am not so familiar with them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: number one skill of a productive software engineer is to break down a challenge into many solvable subproblems and solve each then stitch the subanswers back into nailing  the big problem ... think about this an then focus on getting each sub problem to work ... luckily in today's world solutions are just a search away but thinking and problem solving is key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
mkmv() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"; }
zmv -n -P mkmv '(*)_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_(*)(.png)' '$2/$1$3'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy).

Or with any POSIX-like shell (though without the safeguards of `zmv`):

```
for file in *_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_*.png; do
  dir=${file#*_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_}
  dir=${dir%.*}
  mkdir -p -- "$dir" &&
    mv -- "$file" "${file%%_leftImg8bit_foggy_beta_*}.png"
done
```